# Botframework emulator not getting connected

Tags: botframework, skype, azure-language-understanding

i am trying to use bot framework emulator to connect to my BOT. It is giving error as

Exception: Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Access Denied).
[File of type 'text/plain']

when i looked in the details of the error message it shows service url as http://localhost:31727

but my bot url is http://localhost:3979/api/messages

Can you please help me finding the problem here?

i have attached full error message below.

[image]

{
  "type": "message",
  "timestamp": "2017-03-08T09:51:40.142Z",
  "serviceUrl": "http://localhost:31727",
  "channelId": "emulator",
  "from": {
    "id": "l0352n0fl2ja1ede6",
    "name": "Bot"
  },
  "conversation": {
    "id": "67infihmnjcl68bd7c"
  },
  "recipient": {
    "id": "default-user"
  },
  "locale": "en-US",
  "text": "Exception: Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Access Denied).",
  "attachments": [
    {
      "contentType": "text/plain",
      "content": "   at System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode()\r\n   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Luis.LuisService.d__3.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()\r\n   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Luis.Extensions.<QueryAsync>d__3.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()\r\n   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.LuisDialog`1.<MessageReceived>d__7.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()\r\n   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.DialogTask.ThunkResume`1.d__5.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()\r\n   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.Wait`2.-PollAsync>d__19.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()\r\n   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.Frame`1.-PollAsync>d__9.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()\r\n   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.Fiber`1.-PollAsync>d__16.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.Wait`2.Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.IAwaiter<T>.GetResult()\r\n   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Chain.LoopDialog`1.d__3.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()\r\n   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.DialogTask.ThunkResume`1.<Rest>d__5.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()\r\n   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.Wait`2.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Internals-Fibers-IWait<C>-PollAsync>d__19.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()\r\n   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.Frame`1.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Internals-Fibers-IFrameLoop<C>-PollAsync>d__9.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()\r\n   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.Fiber`1.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Internals-Fibers-IFiberLoop<C>-PollAsync>d__16.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()\r\n   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.DialogTask.d__23.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()\r\n   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.ReactiveDialogTask.d__3.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()\r\n   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.ScoringEventLoop`1.d__5.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()\r\n   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.PersistentDialogTask.d__4.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.PersistentDialogTask.d__4.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()\r\n   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.ExceptionTranslationDialogTask.d__2.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()\r\n   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.SerializeByConversation.d__4.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()\r\n   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.SetAmbientThreadCulture.d__2.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()\r\n   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.PostUnhandledExceptionToUser.d__5.MoveNext()"
    }
  ],
  "entities": [],
  "replyToId": "fc5lb3ii344hk7hnac",
  "id": "jmi06madf5020naii",
  "localTimestamp": "2017-03-08T15:21:40+05:30"
}
Log

Comment: Are you also setting the AppId and AppSecret in the emulator or are u leaving those empty?

Comment: I am leaving them as empty.

Comment: I am leaving them as empty. i am connecting my localhost. do we need to provide appID andAppSecret there as well? if yes then where can i get  the values for these?

Comment: No. Empty is ok

Answer (score 0):

My guess that the configuration with your bot is OK. Mostly likely, that the problem causes by Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Luis.LuisService (on the attached stack) to which you don't provide the correct credentials that is why you get 401.

Try to implement a simpler bot (hello word) to verify that your connection with the emulator is working.

PS. You can run Fiddler to see all requests and see which one is actually failed.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to put the AppId and AppSecret in the Emulator? You can find those values in `Web.config` file in your project.

```
<appSettings>
   <add key="MicrosoftAppId" value="YourAppId" />
   <add key="MicrosoftAppPassword" value="YourAppPassword" />
</appSettings>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing similar issue and fixed by adding below appSettings in config file:

```
 <add key="LuisAppId" value="2342342323423423424"/>
 <add key="LuisAPIKey" value="2342343453423423423"/>
 <add key="LuisAPIHostName" value="westeurope.api.cognitive.microsoft.com"/>
```

PS: Make sure to add above settings specific to your application :>